# Problema con libreria fstream (No escribe sobre el archivo .txt)

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Hola tengo un problema con mi programacion, necesito crear un programa que le pregunte al usuario el nombre del archivo con el cual guardarlo y tambien cuantas lineas de texto quiere que pongan y que poner en esas lineas, el programa si crea el archivo pero al momento de querer que escriba dentro se salta la primer linea y solo pone un enter, supongamos que quiero escribir 2 lineas dentro del txt, la primer linea la pondra como un enter y en la segunda si pondra lo que yo le escriba, al hacer eso en la consola solo me lo marca como si no hubiera escrito nada y repite la pregunta, entre las pruebas que realice se me ocurrio poner un <= y asi es como puedo escribir las lineas deseadas pero la primera la sigue dejando como espacio en blanco quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de resolverse problema y que no ponga un enter [image: Imagen de la consola donde se ve como no me deja escribir en la primer linea][image: Imagen del archivo TXT que muestra como reliza un salto de linea]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void escribir();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    escribir();
    return 0;
}

void escribir(){
    ofstream miArchivo;
    
    string nombreArchivo;
    cout<<"Como se llama el archivo?"<<endl;
    getline(cin,nombreArchivo);
    nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo + ".txt";
    miArchivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(), ios::out);
    
    if(!miArchivo.fail()){
        cout<<"todo OK"<<endl;
        string linea;
        int tamArchivo = 0;
        cout<<"Cuantas lineas quieres que tenga el archivo?"<<endl;
        cin >> tamArchivo;
        for (int i = 0; i < tamArchivo; i++){
            cout<<"Que quieres que diga en esta linea?"<<endl;
            getline(cin,linea);
            miArchivo<< linea <<endl;
        }
        miArchivo.close();
    }else{
        cout<<"error al abrir el archivo =("<<endl;
        exit(2);    
    }           
}
```

Comment: Al extraer con `std::cin>>`, se ignoran los espacios, nuevas lineas, tabs, etc. Enconces cuando lee el `2`, en el stream queda el salto de linea. Cuando lees con `getline`, lo primero que se topara sera ese salto de linea, llegando al comportamiento que comentas. La solucion es simple, justo luego del `cin >> tamArchivo;`, ignoras lo que quede en el stream hasta el siguiente salto de linea. Con tus includes añade `#include<limits>`, y luego de leer añade `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`.

Comment: Bro muchisimas gracias me funciono a la primera, me arrodillo ante ti hermano